# How does merkle proofs work on merkle patricia Trees?

Tags: blockchain

I understand how merkle patricia trees work but i cant seem to figure out how merkle proofs work on merkle patricia trees, there seems to be little documentation about this.

Could we verify an account and account state with the endpoint eth_getProof?
How would it be done there?